# Ошибка 500 , как только запускается локальный сервер Flask

Tags: python, flask

Код :

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def hello() -> str:
    return print('Python Flask Framework')


app.run()
```

То , как это выглядит в браузере : [image: Ошибка на веб-странице]

То , что выводит консоль после запуска программы :

[image: Консоль]

Comment: уберите print, оставьте: return 'Python Flask Framework'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как должно быть:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def hello() -> str:
    return 'Python Flask Framework'

app.run()
```

В вашем коде print('Python Flask Framework') возвращает None, вот и ошибка, то есть в итоге метод hello() вместо строки возвращает None.